# Find/extract a sequence of integers within a list in python

Tags: python

I want to find a sequence of n consecutive integers within a sorted list and return that sequence. This is the best I can figure out (for n = 4), and it doesn't allow the user to specify an n.

```
my_list = [2,3,4,5,7,9]
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if my_list[i+1] == my_list[i]+1 and my_list[i+2] == my_list[i]+2 and my_list[i+3] == my_list[i]+3:
        my_sequence = list(range(my_list[i],my_list[i]+4))

my_sequence = [2,3,4,5]
```

I just realized this code doesn't work and returns an "index out of range" error, so I'll have to mess with the range of the for loop.

Comment: By a sequence do you mean a difference of 1?

Comment: @AnandSKumar yes, although the above code could easily be edited to search for a sequence with a difference of "m"

Comment: And there would only be one such sequence?

Comment: @AnandSKumar that is correct

Comment: and do you know this difference beforehand? I mean you would you give the difference to search for manually? Or let the program try to find out the difference, if latter, what if there are multiple sequences in the list, with multiple differences?

Comment: @AnandSKumar yes, for my application, i know the "difference" i am looking for and i know that there is only one sequence in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short and concise way is to fill an array with numbers every time you find the next integer is the current integer plus 1 (until you already have N consecutive numbers in array), and for anything else, we can empty the array:

```
arr = [4,3,1,2,3,4,5,7,5,3,2,4]
N = 4
newarr = []

for i in range(len(arr)-1):
    if(arr[i]+1 == arr[i+1]):
        newarr += [arr[i]]
        if(len(newarr) == N):
            break
    else:
        newarr = []
```

When the code is run, newarr will be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a straight-forward solution.  It's not as efficient as it might be, but it will be fine unless you have very long lists:

```
myarray = [2,5,1,7,3,8,1,2,3,4,5,7,4,9,1,2,3,5]
for idx, a in enumerate(myarray):
    if myarray[idx:idx+4] == [a,a+1,a+2,a+3]:
        print([a, a+1,a+2,a+3])
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a nested master result list, then go through `my_sorted_list` and add each item to either the last list in the master (if discontinuous) or to a new list in the master (if continuous):

```
>>> my_sorted_list = [0,2,5,7,8,9]
>>> my_sequences = []
>>> for idx,item in enumerate(my_sorted_list):
...     if not idx or item-1 != my_sequences[-1][-1]:
...         my_sequences.append([item])
...     else:
...         my_sequences[-1].append(item)
...
>>> max(my_sequences, key=len)
[7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#size = length of sequence
#span = the span of neighbour integers
#the time complexity is O(n) 
def extractSeq(lst,size,span=1):
    lst_size = len(lst)
    if lst_size < size:
        return []
    for i in range(lst_size - size + 1):
        for j in range(size - 1):
            if lst[i + j] + span == lst[i + j + 1]:
                continue
            else:
                i += j
                break
        else:
            return lst[i:i+size]
    return []
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = [2,3,4,5,7,9]
for j in range(len(mylist)):
      m=mylist[j]
      idx=j
      c=j
      for i in range(j,len(mylist)):
               if mylist[i]<m:
                          m=mylist[i]
                          idx=c
               c+=1
      tmp=mylist[j]
      mylist[j]=m
      mylist[idx]=tmp
print(mylist)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).